# Problem with the function N with second argument

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I was asked to look at a complicated definite integral that could be integrated analytically, but numerically did not behave as expected. After a lot of simplifications I arrived at the following:

```
In[4]:= int= Integrate[x BesselJ[0, 1/x], {x, 0, 1/2000}]

Out[4]= -(1999999/8000000)+EulerGamma/4-
        31250 HypergeometricPFQ[{1,1},{2,3,3},-1000000]+(3 Log[10])/4
```

When we inspect the plot of the integrand, we see that the absolute value of the integral must be considerably less than $2\times 10^{-5}$. We find:

```
In[5]:= N[int]

Out[5]= -2.04448*10^-12

In[6]:= N[int, 5]

Out[6]= 1.6212
```

The second result seems to be wrong. The culprit is the hypergeometric function:

```
In[7]:= N[ HypergeometricPFQ[{1,1},{2,3,3},-1000000]]

Out[7]= 0.0000518798

In[8]:= N[ HypergeometricPFQ[{1,1},{2,3,3},-1000000], 5]

Out[8]= 6.5424*10^-17
```

I also observed the very frustrating behaviour that I cannot always reproduce the incorrect output shown above. At the moment, *Mathematica* behaves stable: when I evaluate the above cells once again, I obtain the same output. But not rarely I observed that the results of `N` with a second argument suddenly were in agreement with the output without a second argument. To see the erroneous behavior again, I had to change the upper limit in the integral a little bit. I am running version 11.3 under Windows 10.

Am I right that the above arbitrary precision result for `HypergeometricPFQ` is incorrect? Can somebody reproduce the incorrect result?

Comment: `NIntegrate[x BesselJ[0, 1/x], {x, 0, 1/2000}, WorkingPrecision -> 32]` suggests the arb. prec. result is wrong. and the machine precision result is accurate. (V11.3.0)

Comment: Also suggested by `N[HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1}, {2, 3, 3}, -1000000], 100]`

Comment: @Ilian. Your result shows that you arrived at the correct result. My frustration is that sometimes, I do not know when, I get this correct result as well. Did you see the incorrect result?

Comment: What version are you using? In Version 11.3 I get consistent and correct answers for all these cases.

Comment: @TheDoctor, Thanks. It looks like I am the only one getting this incorrect result (V11.3, windows). I reported it to WRI.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround. The integral under consideration, after making a substitution, can be expressed as

$$\int_{2000}^\infty\frac{J_0(u)}{u^3}\mathrm du$$

Through Mellin transform techniques, this can be converted to a Meijer $G$ expression:

$$\frac{1}{8}\operatorname{G}_{1,3}^{2,0}\left(\frac{2000}{2},\frac{1}{2}\middle |{{1}\atop{-1,0,-1}}\right)$$

or in *Mathematica* syntax, `MeijerG[{{}, {1}}, {{-1, 0}, {-1}}, 2000/2, 1/2]/8`. Using `FunctionExpand[]` on it confirms the closed form given in the OP.

This seems to work with arbitrary precision, unlike the hypergeometric expression:

```
N[MeijerG[{{}, {1}}, {{-1, 0}, {-1}}, 2000/2, 1/2]/8, 5]
   -2.0445*10^-12
```

Alternatively, a slight change in the Mellin route yields the equivalent Meijer $G$ expression

$$\frac{1}{8}\operatorname{G}_{3,1}^{0,2}\left(\frac{2}{2000},\frac{1}{2}\middle |{{1,2,2}\atop{0}}\right)$$

(in *Mathematica* form, `MeijerG[{{1, 2}, {2}}, {{}, {0}}, 2/2000, 1/2]/8`) which is related to the first one via the ["flip identity"](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.19.E1). This, too, seems to also work for arbitrary precision evaluations.

Comment: Just back from a short holiday, I found your answer. That is a wonderful piece of mathematics! I forwarded your answer to the person who asked me to look at the integral.